# How to run command line program as a separate process in c#(mono) in linux?

Tags: c#, mono, 7zip

So I'm trying to zip some files with 7z from a c# program. I've tried all the possible combinations I could find online. Here's how the code looks:

```
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo() { FileName = "/usr/bin/7z", Arguments = " \"" + command.CommandText + " \"" };
        Process proc = new Process() { StartInfo = startInfo, };
        //proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        //proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        proc.Start();
        //string output = proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
        proc.WaitForExit();
```

I get the following output:

```
Usage:
xdg-open [OPTION...] { file | URL }

Help Options:
  -h, --help       Show help options

Application Options:
  --version        Show program version
```

when I run the full command string in terminal, it works. Why does it try to open it with xdg-open and why it fails? I also tried to run it through /bin/bash, using 7z(or /usr/bin/7z) as an argument, with or without -c option, but all of those don't work. Thanks!

Edit1: When I turn UseShellExecute off, the following exception is thrown:

```
InvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: ApplicationName='/usr/bin/7z', CommandLine=' "a /home/dusan/test/asdasd.7z /home/dusan/Profil.html "', CurrentDirectory='', Native error= Cannot find the specified file
```

Edit2: The program is on the system, here's a screenshot:

[image]

Plus, when I run `whereis 7z`, I get

```
7z: /usr/bin/7z /usr/share/man/man1/7z.1.gz
```

Plus, I already wrote that it works from terminal.
The same error is there if I remove the quotes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The underlying error appears to be due to the program not being on the system. Based on the chat conversation, the user has installed and is running monodevelop via flatpak, which uses a container mechanism. As a consequence the file may appear to be on his desktop, but it's not in the container that is running the monodevelop instance.

When I use `UseShellExecute=true` with a bogus executable name I get:

```
xdg-open: unexpected argument 'a bob.7z helloworld.cs'
Try 'xdg-open --help' for more information.
```

When I use `UseShellExecute=false` with a bogus exeuctable name I get:

```
System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): ApplicationName='/usr/bin/7zx', CommandLine=' "a bob.7z helloworld.cs" ', CurrentDirectory='', Native error= Cannot find the specified file
```

Now, onto the text being passed to the command - the command line parser will attempt to split the arguments passed internally, so if you pass the string:

```
" \"a hello.7z file1 file2\" "
```

it will get parsed and split into a single argument `a hello.7z file1 file2`, which will fail on the 7z command line:

```
Command Line Error:
Unsupported command:
a bob.7z helloworld.cs
```

so you need to be conscious of the quoting that you're using - If the files have spaces in them, then I would quote them explicitly, otherwise I would skip quoting entirely.

The reason that it's using `xdg-open` is that there appears to be an implicit setting of the `UseShellExecute` property on the `ProcessStartInfo`. You should turn this off:

```
var startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo() {
    FileName = "/usr/bin/7z",
    Arguments = " \"" + command.CommandText + " \"",
    UseShellExecute = false
};
```

I can't reproduce this issue from my instance of mono, but the fact that it's invoking `xdg-open` implies that [this is the case](https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/e9913fdc487622073a0827f32f845b637163590d/mono/metadata/w32process-unix.c#L2163).

Comment: I can reproduce both errors when the file `/usr/bin/7z` is not on the system. Are you sure it's there?

Comment: In other details, the quoting is incorrect - don't quote the command line like that, as it ends up passing a single string `"a blah.7z file1 file2"` to `7z`, which doesn't work.

Comment: The program is there, I updated the answer. Can you provide the code you used to reproduce it, and when it works.

Comment: I've uploaded a gist: https://gist.github.com/petesh/89c081691532b98dd3ff2aa116d20b58 that exhibits all the issues I mention in my answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168912/discussion-between-petesh-and-dusan-milosevic).